# keep only 3 first items

Tags: powershell, split, cut

I'm trying to sort a list and get only the elements that gave 3 separators
example:

```
paris/sales/  
paris/sales/14tharrdt/  
paris/sales/14tharrdt/shop1/  
paris/sales/14tharrdt/shop2/  
london/direction/  
london/direction/boss/  
london/direction/boss/secretary/  
london/direction/boss/secretary/official/  
london/direction/boss/CEO/  
new-york/direction/boss/  
new-york/direction/boss/delegation/
london/otherservice/office1/
paris/service1/test/
new-yotk/service1/test/
```

I'd like to only keep following items:

```
london/otherservice/office1/
paris/service1/test/
new-yotk/service1/test/
```

only the lines whith 3 separators and nothing behind

Is there a way to do this with PowerShell?

Comment: So you want to keep only items that start with one of these 3 lines?

Comment: Do you want to keep things like `london/direction/boss/secretary` (no trailing slash) or `paris//14tharrdt/` (consecutive slashes) as well?

Comment: Your example doesnt make sense for me?

Comment: in my list, i only want to keep lines whith 3 slashes and nothing behind and not all entries with 3 slashes

Comment: i'd like to have  
  london/otherservice/office1/
  paris/service1/test/
  new-yotk/service1/test/

and not

   paris/sales/14tharrdt/  
   london/direction/boss/  
   new-york/direction/boss/  
   new-york/direction/boss/
   london/otherservice/office1/
   paris/service1/test/
   new-yotk/service1/test/

Comment: I can't see a pattern / alogirthm for that? Please explain

Comment: i have an active directory where i want to check users department to get only departments with no sub-services under the third level
example:

Comment: i try to do this with text file

Comment: if you have another solution

Comment: Departments or OUs? Do you read the information directly from AD or do you get it by other means?

Comment: departments in fact our AD structure doesn't fit our organizationnal structure

Comment: the only way to know in witch service works a person is to look at his department

Comment: i have information directly from AD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as easy as this:

```
$array |Where-Object { $_.split("/").length -eq 4 }
```

Comment: This works as longs as ever value has a trailing `/` like the sample has. Will also include `london/service1/test/foo`.

Comment: i coped with this answer and got what  wanted

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Gerald Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212107/gerald-schneider), no need to use a `regex` here. But if you want to, here is a solution:

```
$array | Where { $_ -match '^(?:[^\/]+\/){3}$' }
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

```
^(?:[^\/]+\/){3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yB3jh5DYLBVqryEm)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ2hY3/1)

Comment: thnaks for your help

Comment: i miade a more precise example above sorry for the misexplanation